# How do the particles in a standing wave vibrate in phase within half a wavelength?

Tags: waves

I would like to have a better understanding of phase difference when talking about stationary waves. How exactly are particles in phase within half a wavelength in a stationary wave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standing wave is formed when two identical waves travelling in opposite directions meet and superimpose on each other. This usually happens when one wave is the reflection of the other.

Now, to better understand this, see [this animation](http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Demos/superposition/standing.gif),

[image]

It is pretty apparent that the black particle that doesn't appear to be moving will be in phase with the particle that is to the right of the particle that is going up and down. That is, it will be in phase with the particle after half a wavelength (after one crest/trough).

Similarly, the particle that is going up and down will be in phase with the particle that is on the next crest/trough. That is, after half a wavelength.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: What don't you understand? You know what a wavelength is right? Distance between one crest and trough?

Comment: In one loop, are all the particles in phase?

Comment: No. See the animation, the two black dots are not in phase. The first dot is in phase with the dot to the right of the moving dot. Please accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I didn't know that gifs are supported haha. Thanks for the edit Emilio. It's funny how the other answer was accepted when it basically just referred to my answer and had less explanation.

Comment: I have the same belief as you. I also believe schools ruin brains.

Comment: @ParthVader, I noticed i got downvoted and I was wondering why then I read the latest comments. Fair enough! ;)

Comment: Haha it's cool. High five Asad!

Comment: @user42733 PhotonBoom seems much more intiutive than yours. you seem to be reciting from textbook

Answer (score 1):

In phase simply means that the particle are moving at the same direction at all times. For a standing wave, this is achieved only if they have the same amplitude at all times.

Using parthvader's animation [below](http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Demos/superposition/standing.gif), if you take any of the two black dots, that represent a particle, you can see that all the points that move in parallel to that point are all half a wavelength from each other.

Comment: In one loop, all the particles must be in phase, which is why they're interfering constructively, right?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking. Forget about the 2 waves combining to give the resultant wave. Just focus on the standing wave. If you place a particle in each point on the standing wave then two particles are said to be in phase if they move in parallel to each other & towards the same direction at any given point in time.